# Question about the structure of finite abelian groups theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation, abelian-groups

I have been trying to follow the proof for the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups from [libretexts.org](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Abstract_and_Geometric_Algebra/Abstract_Algebra%3A_Theory_and_Applications_(Judson)/13%3A_The_Structure_of_Groups/13.01%3A_Finite_Abelian_Groups), but unfortunately I got stuck right at the very end, at the proof of the following lemma:

> Let $G$ be a finite abelian $p$-group and suppose that $g∈G$ has maximal order. Then $G$ is isomorphic to $⟨g⟩×H$ for some subgroup $H$ of $G$.

The proof uses induction on n, where $|G|=p^n$, and shows that there exists $h\notin \langle g \rangle$ such that $ord(h)=p$. Using the notation $H = \langle h \rangle$, the induction hypothesis is applied, namely that there exists a subgroup $K$ of $G$ containing $H$ such that $$G/H \ \ \cong \  \langle gH \rangle × \ \ K/H$$ (this can be done since $\langle gH \rangle$ must have maximal order in $G/H$ and, following the third isomorphism theorem, any subgroup of $G/H$ is of the form $K/H$, $K$ as described earlier).

However, I can't understand the last two lines, namely why the results mentioned earlier lead to: $$G = \langle g \rangle K$$

I think it has something to do with the correspondence theorem, but, unfortunately, I can't put my finger on it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you're very close. Write out the correspondence theorem with your groups (look at the "backwards" direction, it states a bijection exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ingredients are two facts, namely
$$G/H \cong \langle gH\rangle \times K/H$$
as you wrote, and the fact that
$$ \langle g\rangle \cap K = 0$$
which they also prove. This later fact means that we have an isomorphism
$$\langle gH\rangle \times K/H \cong \lbrace g^m k H \: |\: k\in K\rbrace $$
Given by $(g^m H, kH) \mapsto g^m k H$. As we have
$$G/H \cong \lbrace aH \: |\: a\in G\rbrace$$
and using the first isomorphism, we get that every $a$ can be written uniquely as $g^m k$ for some $k\in K$. It all boils down to the correspondence between the quotient group and the group of cosets.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, however there still is a part of their proof I can't quite understand. Why is the intersection of <g> and K 0? More precisely, why is the intersection of <gH> and K/H composed only of H? (I can see why H is in both subgroups) Does this stem directly from the first relation you wrote? If so, why exactly?

Comment: That is a great question. Having looked at the proof a bit, it seems that they use implicitly in their induction the fact that the two groups should have trivial intersection. Indeed, it is true in the base case, and they prove it for the induction step as well, but they should have said so more explicitly.